# What are the exact damage numbers for Widowmaker after the patch on June 14, 2016?

Tags: overwatch

> Base damage decreases from 15 to 12 (damage multiplier doesn't change)

So what are the exact old and new numbers after this update ?

I assume that the **"Headshot damage multiplier increase from x2 to x2.5"** will cancel the above, when performing a headshot?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this means bodyshots will max at 120 from 150

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The changes reduce Widowmaker's bodyshot damage, while not changing her headshots.

Fully charged sniper shots deal 10x base damage. Her body shots now deal a maximum of 120 damage (previously 150). This means that she will no longer kill Zenyatta and Tracer from full health in a single body shot.

The 2.5 headshot multiplier means her headshots will deal a maximum of 300 damage- the same amount as they did before.

Comment: I assume that made it so some of the heros she could previously kill in one body shot she now can't. Which ones? Zenyatta, I think?

Comment: @DCShannon Zenyatta and Tracer.

Comment: Edited that in for you. +1